What do we know of the ages of the apostles?
This came up in a recent homily, with the priest discussing how many of us feel like it may be too late for us to make a difference in the world, and then pivoting to how we don't know for certain how old the apostles were, and that they may have had people considered past their prime of life who have nonetheless gone on to do great things. We know that Simon and Andrew were helping their father with the fishing, which suggests that they were below a certain age range, having a surviving father who was able to participate in hard work. Peter seems to have had a wife (or at least a sick mother-in-law) at the time of joining. Tradition has it that John dies in the late first century. And we know that it is generally accepted that Jesus was 33 when he died. And, of course, artwork over the ages has depicted the apostles as everything from ruddy youth who forewent a traditional adult career to follow an itinerant rabbi to aged elders who were clearly venerable enough to continue to pass on wisdom after Jesus's death.
Is there any proof in the text, or in related writings, of the ages of the apostles at the time of joining Jesus?

The answer is, almost nothing!!  We are not told so we do not know.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

I did read through the tour. It seemed like the question was within spec (although I don't honestly know if it is answerable, part of the reason I asked).
